# accessing private struct inside class using class member function

Tags: c++, class, structure

Trying to write a setter function for a private structure inside a class. Haven't found a declaration method that allows access to the structure.

The structure may not be moved outside of the class. The function must be a member of the class. Forward declarations may not be used.

```
class Editor
{
public:
    void setName ( string s );
private:
    struct Object
    {
        string name;
    }Instance;
}Ed;

void Editor::setName ( string s )
{
    name = s;  // no access
}
```

==================================

```
class Editor
{
public:
    friend void setName ( Editor &m , string s );
private:
    struct Object
    {
        int name;
    }Instance;
}Ed;

void setName ( Editor &m , string s )
{
    name = s; // no access
}
```

==================================

```
class Editor
{
public:
    friend void setName ( Object &m , string s ); //invalid declaration (  Object is undefined )
private:
    struct Object
    {
        string name;
    }Instance;
}Ed;
```

Comment: Please post real code.

Answer (score 1):

```
void Editor::setName ( string s )
{
    name = s;  // no access
}
```

Of course you can't do that. There is no object named `name` in `Editor`. There is, however, an object named `Instance` that **contains** an object named `name`, and you can set that value with `Instance.name = s;`.

Comment: `void Editor::setName ( string s )
{
    Instance.name = s;  // expression must be a modifiable lvalue
}`

Comment: It **is** a modifiable lvalue. Unless the code you're compiling is different from the code you posted.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
class Editor
{
public:
    void setName ( string s );
private:
    struct Object
    {
        string name;
    }Instance;
}Ed;

void Editor::setName ( string s )
{
    Instance.name = s; 
}
```

Comment: See above comment. Results in the error "expression must be a modifiable lvalue" (referring to Instance in the function)